# how to find out the apache version installed in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apache2

how to find out the Apache server version installed in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 117):

Open the terminal and type:

```
apache2 -v
```

`-v`  Print the version of apache2, and then exit.

Answer (score 9):

From the terminal you can enter: (lowercase `-v`)

```
apachectl -v
```

or to get even more compile info on Apache enter: (uppercase `-V`)

```
apachectl -V
```

of course as mention by @karel you can also use `apache2` instead of `apachectl`... just giving an alternative. This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm using Apache 2.4.37.

Comment: this was a solved question from march 2015. why and how is your alternative answer any useful ?

Comment: I guess if you run the same command twice, you get a different result?

Comment: One is a lowercase `v` and the other is an uppercase `V` which could be different levels of verbosity for `apachectl`, but I can't find any indication these flags exist in the manpage.

Comment: @Ali Çarıkçıoğlu, well for one thing karel's solution didn't work for me at all with Apache 2.2.22 (not pre-installed). Both solutions from god_is_love were very useful for me.

Comment: This solution also helped us (and the first didn't). Admittedly, this isn't on ubuntu 14.04, but the title didn't disclose that, and we ended up here nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

if you have PHP installed with you apache2, you can find it in $_SERVER variable or with `phpinfo()` function:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
phpinfo();
```

returns (on my computer):

```
'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => string '<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server …</address>
'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)'

# and in phpinfo arrays:
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```